# Sorting of List<Object>

Tags: android, sorting, listobject

I need to sort the products by High to Low & Low to High of its Price.I have done Low to High by using following code.But dont know how to implement High To Low?

Your answer is more appreciated...

```
 public static Comparator<Restaurant_Beam> strPriceFilterL2H = new Comparator<Restaurant_Beam>() {

      @Override
        public int compare(Restaurant_Beam lhs, Restaurant_Beam rhs) {
            int CompareResult = 0;
            if (Config.L2HFilterClicked == "L2H") {
                CompareResult = (int) Math.round(Double.parseDouble(lhs.getIG_SALES_PRICE()) - Double.parseDouble(rhs.getIG_SALES_PRICE()));

            } 
//Used else if for H2L.But did not get it as perfect

else if (Config.L2HFilterClicked == "H2L") {
                CompareResult = (int) Math.round(Double.parseDouble(lhs.getIG_SALES_PRICE()) + Double.parseDouble(rhs.getIG_SALES_PRICE()));

            }
            return CompareResult;
        }
    };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the second compare expression to this one:

```
CompareResult = (int) Math.round(Double.parseDouble(Double.parseDouble(rhs.getIG_SALES_PRICE()) - Double.parseDouble(lhs.getIG_SALES_PRICE()));
```

Also I'd like to point out a few things

- consider doing `Double` comparison with epsilon
- it's a good practice to check objects before comparing them
- parsing each time you compare is really bad design. It would be better if you parse values somewhere in advance, consider changing your type. Currently it's not efficient.

Comment: Thank you so much @Ivan Leonenko